# Getting total of column using class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following table rows in a form that I need to add as total. To do that I need to remove "$" and "," from the amount.

```
    <tr>
    <td>football</td>
    <td class="price" style="text-align: right">$23,432.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>baseball</td>
    <td class="prcice" style="text-align: right">$23,432.00</td>
    </tr>
     <div id="result"></div>
```

Function to add is

```
 function calculateSum() {
              var sumtotal = 0;
              $(".price").each(function () {

                  var value = $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\$\$/g, '$',','));                
                 alert("value" + value);
                  if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                      sumtotal += parseFloat(value);
                  }
              });
              alert(sumtotal);
              $('#result').text(sumtotal);
          };
```

Than inside my document.ready() i am using this to call.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.price').each(function () {
                  $(calculateSum);
              });
});
```

It gives me 0 for result and for value i get alert value[object Object]
Please help, how I can get the total properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `replace` method correctly, it should take only two parameters. The first one is the regular expression or string you want to replace and the second one is the new value. Try this:

```
var value = "$23,432.00"; // here you pick the value from your table cell
var floatValue = parseFloat(value.replace(/[\$,]/g, ''))
alert(floatValue)
```

Also, take a look at the answer from @charlietfl, he is pointing some other problems you should correct in your code.

Answer (score 0):

All sorts of issues at play here:

First `$(calculateSum);` is not a way to call a regular function. It should be simply `calculateSum();`

Next within the `calculateSum()` you loop over each `$('.ethnTotal')` but in `$(document).ready` you create another loop for `$('.ethnTotal').each` and are trying to call `calculateSum()` on each pass of that loop

This will exponentially inflate your calcultaion!!